# jquery, ajax and submitting a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, preventdefault

I am trying to make all the forms in the page to do something when they are submitted and to prevent their default behavior using this jQuery code:

```
$("form").not("#loginf").submit(function (){
    event.preventDefault();
    var inputs = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url: "pages/"+page+".php",
      type: "POST",  
      data: inputs+'&action='+param,
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        update(html);
        rs();
    }).fail(function (){
        window.location = "/CMS/";
    });
});
```

and this html form (just 1 of them):

```
<form method="POST" name="cpass">
    <span class="brow"><span class="label">סיסמא ישנה:</span><input type="password" name="oldp" /></span>
    <span class="brow"><span class="label">סיסמא חדשה:</span><input type="password" name="newp" /></span>
    <span class="brow"><span class="label">וידוא סיסמא:</span><input type="password" name="rnewp" /></span>
    <span class="brow"><input type="submit" name="cpasssub" value="שנה סיסמא"/></span>
</form>
```

The problam is that the jQuery function doesn't even get executed (i checked by placing an alert there).

What is wrong here?

Comment: you are not passing event in submit(function(event))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `event` arguments within submit

```
  $("form").not("#loginf").submit(function (event){
```